# Using If/Else statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, jquery-effects

I am using a nav filter to highlight certain projects which are represented in a couple of lists.  Each nav button, when clicked, will add the respective border around the projects that fall under that category.  I have a very simplified version of the code here in jsFiddle.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LgLwx6c/8/)

```
//what do i do here?  if/else
$('li#all-btn').click(function() {
    $("#projects").find("li.wrap").toggleClass("highlight-all");
});
```

The jsFiddle is not highlighting all of them like my original code does (adds black border), but I am wanting to change that to where it will highlight every project with their respective border color.  I like the ability to toggle the border on and off as well.

I am thinking that the best way to achieve this would be an if/else statement within the jQuery, such as IF the project contains this class, THEN toggleClass("respective class").  How can I achieve this effect?

Edit:  Sorry, I probably didn't make this clear enough.  So the goal is to have when the all-btn gets clicked, that each item will be highlighted according to their respective color.  As it sits now, each one will be highlighted black, but the goal is to have all colors showing. For example, the web design will be highlighted red, the graphic design green, and the flat design blue, all by clicking the all button.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/. The other thing to note is that your JS is already doing what you described. `$("#projects").find("li.wrap").toggleClass("highlight-all");` will toggle the highlight-all class if the li inside of #projects has a class of wrap.

Comment: Ive edited the goal.  Goal is to have them all highlighted when clicking all, but each their own color, not black.

Comment: This would be handled with the same JS, but an addition to your CSS. I'll make a quick example for ya.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` on line 32 in the CSS. The code works if you remove that.

And you probably need a `black` border on `.highlight-all` as you mention in the question.

```
.highlight-all {
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7LgLwx6c/2/).

Comment: Thanks for catching that, careless mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional `}` (line 32) in your CSS which breaks the first CSS rule right after it. So that's why your "select all" style doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind all li button and set an extra data to define what category he need to target like:

html:

```
<li class="default-btn" id="web-btn" data-target="web">WEB DESIGN</li>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-filter li').on('click', function() {
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $('.'+target).toggleClass('highlight-'+target);
    });
});
```

I make a jsfiddle with some correction: http://jsfiddle.net/Pik_at/7LgLwx6c/4/

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but are overthinking things. The javascript should be telling the CSS that the elements should be highlighted, and the CSS should be controlling the colors.

You should add a class to each project that indicates which type of project that it is (I used `type_1`, `type_2`, and `type_3`). Your CSS will change the border color when the `highlight` class is applied to the project item.

JS:

```
$('#all-btn').click( function(e) {
    // Prevent the Default Click Action
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#projects').find('li.project').toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="all-btn">Toggle All</a>
<ul id="projects">
    <li class="project type_1">Project</li>
    <li class="project type_2">Project</li>
    <li class="project type_3">Project</li>
    <li class="project type_1">Project</li>
    <li class="project type_2">Project</li>
    <li class="project type_3">Project</li>
    <li class="project type_1">Project</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.project {
    /* Define a default border to avoid stuff shifting */
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.type_1.highlight {
    border-color:red;
}
.type_2.highlight {
    border-color:blue;
}
.type_3.highlight {
    border-color:green;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nnds079o/